# How to go to the previous error in latex document

Tags: auctex

After compiling a LaTeX document with errors I can go to the first error via `TeX-next-error` to the second one by executing this macro again etc. After the last error pressing it once more results in `no more errors`. That makes sense so far. However using `TeX-previous-error` doesn't bring me to the previous error but to the next one. For example if I am by the second error and execute `TeX-previous-error` it jumps to the third error and not to the first one. In particular if `TeX-next-error` reached `no more error`, `TeX-previous-error` doesn't bring you to the last error.

My AucTeX version is 11.89.4

Is this a bug or an intended behavior (why?). Is there any other way to go to back and forward in the error list?

Comment: On my system (emacs 24.5.1 auctex 11.87) `TeX-previous-error` displays `TeX-previous-error: Jumping to previous error not supported`.

Comment: @JeanPierre Going to previous error has been introduced in a later version (I don't remember if it was 11.88 or 11.89)

Comment: I can't verify right now the problem you describe, however you can use TeX-error-overview to have a list of the errors and warnings

Comment: @giordano Thanks for this suggestion, I didn't know `TeX-error-overview`. But I tried it and it looks great with a minor drawback at the first glance which lead me to ask a new question: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/26473/2323 Nevertheless I am interested of how to solve the `TeX-previous-error` problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to give it a look, but I won't have access to Emacs for a couple of days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in AUCTeX, this should have been fixed with [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=commitdiff;h=e4b2e6a76965156257a19bd65f9bc76dfb743b6e).  This change will go live in the next ELPA release or next stable version.

However, note that starting from version 11.88 of the package, it's available a nicely formatted list of errors and warnings that can be accessed with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `TeX-error-overview` <kbd>RET</kbd>, or from the menu `Command` → `Error Overview`.  You can navigate between errors with `n` and `p`.

Comment: Your commit link displays: 

404 - Unknown commit object

Comment: Thank you, there was an extra `9` at the end of the link.